# vb.net DataGridView For Loop Numbering in only Selected Cells

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, for-loop, datagridview

I have a question about for loop in DataGridView. I would like to add a number with a string. For example, when I select cell 1 to 3 and I run my code, then it shows, that cell 1 should be "LTS-1", cell 2 should be "LTS-2" and cell 3 should be "LTS-3" one by one from what I selected first. But in DataGridView shows always reverse, that means cell 1 is "LTS-3", cell 2 is "LTS-2" and cell 3 is "LTS-1". Of course, I tried reverse for loop, it doesn't work also. Here is what I made code in DataGridView. Is there something what I made wrong?

[image]

```
Dim input1 As String
input1 = InputBox("Please, enter a regular text.", "Input Box", "LTS")
If input1 = "" Then Exit Sub

'Dim i As Integer
'For i = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
'    DataGridView1.SelectedCells(i).Value = input1 & "-" & i + 1
'    DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = input1 & "-" & i + 1
'Next

'For i = 0 To DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count - 1
'    DataGridView1.SelectedCells(i).Value = input1 & "-" & i + 1
'    DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = input1 & "-" & i + 1
'Next

Dim j As Integer = 0
For Each selCells As DataGridViewCell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
   'DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = input1 & "-" & j + 1
   'DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).Value = input1 & "-" & j + 1
   DataGridView1.SelectedCells(j).Value = input1 & "-" & j + 1
   j = j + 1
Next
```

Comment: You haven't explained what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I just would like to make a string and numbering of the string. ex) LTS-1 But in DataGridView shows alsways reverse from first cell what user selected.

Comment: That is far too vague an explanation and it needs to be in the question anyway. Edit your question and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, including EXACTLY what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it and what happens when you try.

Comment: I mean, when I select a cell 1 to 3, and I run my code, then normally cell1 value should be "LTS_1", cell2 should be "LTS_2" and cell3 should be "LTS_3" in excel. But in DataGridView shows, that cell1 is "LTS_3", cell2 is "LTS_2" and cell3 is "LTS_1" like this. This is my question why in DataGridView shows always reverse..

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Stop explaining the problem in comments and do what I said, i.e. edit your question and provide a FULL explanation where you should have in the first place.

Comment: Also, you should learn how different types of loops work. The whole point of a `For Each` loop is the loop control variable - `selCells` in your last loop. You're not even using that inside the loop through, so what's the point of the loop? If you want to use an index to access list items then you should be using the type of loop that provides such an index. That's not `For Each`.

Comment: Is the picture showing what you want or what the code actually does?

Comment: Yes, it is. The selection could be multi selection. Rows and columns don't matter. That picture what I captured in excel after I run my code. In excel it works, but in DataGridView shows reverse one by one from what I selected last.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney Thank you for your tip.. But for each loop works in excel. And it shows correct value from what I selected first.

Comment: You should keep in mind when “looping” through any of the grid’s “selected” collections… that the collections “first” element in the collection will be the “last” selected item and the “last” element in the collection will be the “first” selected item.

Comment: ach so, okay. And I found the solution...  Thank you sir.

Comment: If you are trying to keep some order to the numbering, then you should “sort” the elemets in the collection by row number. The row order in the grids “selected” cells collection is going to be based on the order the user selects the cells. Using the control key, the user can select a cell on row 3 then 2, then 10, then 8. Point being, is that if you need the selection “ordered” by something, then you better “sort” the items by the order you want. There is no guarantee the user selected the cells in the order you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 Dim input1 As String
    input1 = InputBox("Please, enter a regular text.", "Input Box", "LTS")
    If input1 = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim list_cells As New List(Of DataGridViewCell)

    Dim j As Integer = 0


    For Each selCells As DataGridViewCell In DataGridView1.SelectedCells
        list_cells.Add(selCells)

    Next
    list_cells = list_cells.OrderBy(Function(x) x.RowIndex).ThenBy(Function(x) x.ColumnIndex).ToList



    For Each selCells As DataGridViewCell In list_cells
        selCells.Value = input1 & "-" & j + 1
        j = j + 1
    Next
```

Thanks